# Pro Tools Playlist Switching

Tags: pro-tools, techniques

I switch between playlists a lot while recording, editing and comping vocals.

Is there a clever trick any of you have found for a hotkey via QuicKeys or is there a new shortcut in Pro Tools 8 or 9 that switches automatically between playlists on a certain track?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any way to change playlist with a keycommand. Maybe you can have the the track in playlist view (so all the playlists appear under your track) and have a shortcuts with QK that copy the first-second-third-fourth-etc. playlist to your main track... just an idea.

What you ask, IF Pro Tools supported applescript (or any other script language) could be added easily (I think): I'm trying to ask for applescript support for Pro Tools, maybe you can spread the word.

http://bit.ly/cfsvWw

Comment: I use "playlist view" all the time. It's great, there's even a "copy selection to main playlist" button (not sure if there's a hotkey for it though...lol...I should really look into that).

Comment: @Shaun there's a shortcut: option control V
with that you can make a quickeys shortcut to automate the copy of a specific playlist to the main playlist

Comment: Thanks @Shaun and Davide. I am unfortunately using Pro Tools 7 still - haven't made the jump. The playlist view option you are talking about is in Pro Tools 8+, right?

Comment: @Ryan Yes, only in PT 8 and 9

Answer (score 2):

Check this forum out for some potential answers.

http://www.nashvillemusicpros.com/forum/topics/1322798:Topic:130783

Same question.

Comment: They are using 7.3-4 however

Comment: Thanks! I read the thread. I guess there isn't much hope for me. I hope Pro Tools figures something out in the future!